# Is there a difference between a stable sort and a sort with two comparisons?

Tags: c++, sorting

This is for C++. I know that a stable sort sorts while keeping in mind the original order of ties, but I recall that the time complexity for stable sort is O(n*logn^2), so I was wondering: if I stored my values into a pair with the first containing the value and the second containing the original position (i.e. [5,2,2,3,1] --> [(5,0),(2,1),(2,2),(3,3),(1,4)]), and I used as my comparator:

```
bool compare(const pair<int,int> &left, const pair<int,int> &right){
     return left.first < right.first || (left.first == right.first && left.second < right.second);
}
```

then wouldn't I have the same effect as stable sort, except in O(nlogn) time now?
If not, what makes them different/similar?

Comment: Don't get misled by complexity bounds. Note that if your comparator is more complicated, your constant factors are increased, even if your big-Oh is the same.

Comment: Also note that `std::stable_sort` is only `O(n log^2 n)` when memory is low.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation in cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_sort), you can see that it is:

> O(N·log(N)2), where N = std::distance(first, last) applications of cmp. If additional memory is available, then the complexity is O(N·log(N)).

So, in general, if there is enough auxiliary memory, then the complexity will be the lower term you specified (and probably using the technique you specify, although the standard doesn't dictate that). However the standard mandates guarantees on operations completing, so if memory is unavailable, it will use a slower, but surer, technique, which doesn't require additional memory.

Comment: But, what about when there's not enough extra memory? The documentation states polyloglinear for that: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort/

Comment: @jkwon0866 See updated answer. Also, I suggest you avoid cplusplus.com.

Comment: Ah shoot, is cplusplus.com inaccurate? I've been using that website this whole time.

Comment: @jkwon0866, Yes, I recommend cppreference.com

Comment: Yes. Feel free to upvote and or accept useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

You recall incorrectly -- there exist stable O(n*log n) sorting algorithms.  See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm#Comparison_sorts) for example.  The version you describe is an application of the [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: But, what about when there's not enough extra memory? The documentation states polyloglinear for that: cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/stable_sort